# wpf localization

Tags: .net, wpf, localization

Which is the best third party tool available for wpf application localization.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254393/2619912) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Passolo](http://www.sdl.com/en/language-technology/products/software-localization/sdl-passolo.asp) is a commercial product that one of my clients uses -- if you have set up your app with all the strings that need to be translated in resource files, the Passolo app sweeps through them, generates files to send off to your translaters, and lets you pull the translated text back in.

This product is not cheap, though, it's definitely more of an enterprise solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305114/recommend-wpf-localization-tool) question -

> - http://www.lingobit.com/
> - http://www.sisulizer.com/
> - http://www.multilizer.com/
>
> Sisulizer and Lingobit claim to handle .NET and WPF but only Lingobit
>   would handle WPF styles correctly.
>
> http://www.schaudin.com/web/page4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have chosen to use this method(it looks like old one, often used in winforms):

> **How to use a ResX file in a WPF application:** Create a Resource
>   (ResX) file in your project or you can
>   reuse the Properties/Resources.resx
>   file. In the Visual Studio Resource
>   designer you have to change the Access
>   Modifier from Internal to Public. This
>   can be found in the top toolbar of the
>   designer. Add the namespace to your
>   XAML View:
>
> ```
> xmlns:p="clr-namespace:Jbe.TestSuite.Infrastructure.Shell.Properties"
>
>
> The Resources can be accessed via the x:Static markup extension of XAML:
>
> <MenuItem Header="{x:Static p:Resources.FileMenu}">
> ```

taken from [here](http://waf.codeplex.com/discussions/557543).

Answer (score 1):

I tested all four tools.

Lingobit can correctly localize RESX resource but failed to extract any string from XAML/BAML. Lingobit reported that XAML component have not id even every single component I had has an id. For me Lingobit is unuseabled for WPF.

Multilizer also failed to scan any XAML/BAML data. In addition I could not even enter any translations. Multilizer is a buggy and extremely difficult application to use. I would not recommend it to anybody.

Sisulizer lets you localize WPF assemblies but popups a message that assembly localization is experimental. However it can correcly localize both RESX and XAML if you speaicy Visual Studio project file (.csproj) instead of assembly file (.exe). No problems with XAML styles.

Passolo worked equally good to Sisulizer. It could localize XAML but did not scan all the properties I wanted.

Lingobit and Multilizer could not localize XAML, Sisulizer only if you have full source code and development enviroment installed, and Passolo misses some strings. I am still waiting for perfect WPF localization tool: a tool that can localize all resources of WPF assemblies.

Comment: And by id you mean x:Uid?

Comment: I use either x:Name or Name. They all (Name, x:Name or x:Uid) should be noticed as valid ids. It seems that Lingobit requires x:Uid.